# Determinant of block matrices of block matrices with different dimensions

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

Please, how can I find the determinant of the following matrix?

$$P=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} A \quad B \\ C \quad 0 \end{array} \right)$$

where $A$ is a 2x2 block matrix, $B$ is a 2x1 matrix, $C$ is a 1x2 matrix and  $0$ is a 1x1 zero matrix.

Such that
$$A=\left( \begin{array} {c,c,c} A_{11} \quad A_{12}\quad B_{11} \\ A_{21} \quad A_{22} \quad B_{21}\\ C_{11} \quad \, C_{12} \quad \, 0 \end{array} \right)$$

I know that for
$$P=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} A \quad B \\ C \quad 0 \end{array} \right)$$
where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $0$ is the $n\times n$ zero matrix
$$\det(P)=\det(-C)\det(B)$$
What will $\det P$ be for unequal dimension block matrices?

Comment: I don't think there would be a specific formula for this, since B and C are not square matrices (so they don't have determinants). The only way is to see the matrix as a whole (not with blocks) and to calculate the determinant.

Comment: The following formula holds $Det(P) = Det(A)Det(-B A^{-1} C)$. You might find it useful. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement.

Comment: @user72829: You might put this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Emin. But how do I manipulate the determinant of a 3*3 block matrix?

Comment: @user72829: Thanks for your comment. But when I used this formula, $Det(P) = Det(A)Det(-C A^{-1} B)$ I solved the problem to a stage and the whole calculation became messy. $A_{11}, A_{12}, A_{21}, A_{22}$ are actually matrices too. But $B_{11},\quad B_{21},\quad C_{11} \quad and \quad C_{12}$ are scalars. So, how do I manipulate the multiplication, $-C A^{-1} B$? When I solved it, it did not conform. Thanks.